# Speech audio databases with phonemes labelled

Tags: data-request, language, english, corpora, audio

Can anyone point me to opensource databases of speech audio with phonemes labelled, 
`.wav` or the like + label files, e.g.

```
# time, phoneme
0.31200 ao
0.41200 th
0.54200 er
...
```

I'd prefer English, several speakers, and various noise levels,
but let's see what's around.
(There's `cmu_*_arctic` from [CMU festvox](http://festvox.org/dbs);
it's pretty old, 2005 — there must be more.)

Answer (score 4):

I am not 100% sure if the following links are useful for you. Please let me know if you are looking for something else.

http://www.iitg.ac.in/ece/emstlab/SRdatabase/introduction.php

http://accent.gmu.edu/howto.php

http://www.signalprocessingsociety.org/technical-committees/list/sl-tc/spl-nl/2012-05/the-rss2015-speech-corpus/

Comment: Thanks @Anastasios; I don't see phoneme label files so far, will ask the RSS2015 people. (Pros might consider phoneme labelling trivial / impossible / useless, comments ?)

Comment: any update on this? did you reach out denis?

Answer (score 1):

There is an auxiliary dataset of phoneme labels for the Librispeech corpus. It can be found here [Zenodo: LibriSpeech Alignments](https://zenodo.org/record/2619474).

Comment: Hi @denis - can you make a new question for that? You can then link it here, and I will try my best to answer

Comment: Jon, [speech-intelligiblity-tests-such-as-rhyme-tests](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/21076/speech-intelligiblity-tests-such-as-rhyme-tests)  -- thanks