# Speech intelligiblity tests such as rhyme tests

Tags: data-request, language, corpora, audio

Can anyoe point me to .wav files or the like for
speech intelligiblity tests, e.g.
[Rhyme tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_test#Modified_Rhyme_Test)
"not, tot, got, pot, hot, lot" ?
What I want are reproducible tests for various hearing aids and settings,
in a quiet room, not speech-in-noise.
(I'm an old guy with high-frequency hearing loss --
https://hearingtest.online says 4 kHz ~ 30 dB down from 2 kHz.)
Any European language would be ok.

((I'd really like to know if hearing aid equalizers can flatten out high-frequency drop,
specifically Phonak P30,
but how to measure the effect on speech ?)